# Generating bordims in TQFTs

Tags: ct.category-theory, differential-topology

A two dimensional TQFT can be described as a commutative Frobenius algebra by breaking up bordisms along submanifolds of codimension one into a set of generating bordisms. I was wondering if there is a similar way to break up bordisms of any dimension along codimension one submanifolds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

András Juhász recently posted a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0668) to the arxiv with a result in this direction.  Of course the answer is much much more complicated than the 2-dimensional case, even just in 3-dimensions.

Somewhat nicer answers can be found if you allow "extended TFTs" where you are allowed to continue cutting in lower dimensions.  The cobordism hypothesis (see [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~lurie/papers/cobordism.pdf) and [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/cobordism.pdf)) is a particularly nice statement in this setting for TFTs extended all the way down to points.  An intermediate example, which is more in the spirit of the Frobenius algebra classification in 2-dimensions, is the Bartlett--Douglas--Schommer-Pries--Vicary classification of 321 TFTs in terms of modular tensor categories ([two](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0945) [of](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06811) the four papers are posted).

Comment: Noah, if I may ask, what are some other recent developments/areas of interest regarding non-extended TQFTs that you are aware of?